# Spring MVC - How to register more than one ArgumentResolver and choose one dynamically in the Controller Method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pagination

I have an ArgumentResolver where i define the fallback situation for my pagination:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 5, Direction.DESC, "id"));
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    }
}
```

And this is how my controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(RequestMappings.SHOW_ALL_ITEMS)
public String showAllItems(Model model, Pageable pageable) {

    PageWrapper<Item> page = new PageWrapper<Item> 
        (itemService.getAllItems(pageable), RequestMappings.SHOW_ALL_ITEMS);
    model.addAttribute("page", page);

    return ViewNamesHolder.SHOW_ALL_ITEMS;
}
```

What if i would like to have another controller method with a different fallback situation? I know that i can register many argument resolver objects. But how do i define which one i use in the controller method in this case? :

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolverWithSizeFive = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolverWithSizeFive.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 5, Direction.DESC, "id"));
        argumentResolvers.add(resolverWithSizeFive);

        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolverWithSizeTen = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolverWithSizeTen.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10, Direction.DESC, "id"));
        argumentResolvers.add(resolverWithSizeTen);
    }
}
```

Comment: little bit offtocpic As far as I recall there is a built-in annotation to specify default values for page request on method level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instances are checked in registration order.

Spring first registers default annotation-based argument resolvers, then type based argument resolvers, then your custom resolvers, then some catch-all resolvers. You can see these in `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#getDefaultArgumentResolvers()`.

In your case, to differentiate between `Pageable` in one handler method vs `Pageable` in another handler method, the only way I can think of is to sublcass and register your own `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instances, ie. one for each type of fallback, that check for a custom annotation that identifies the fallback pageable in its `supportsParameter` method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this sentence? "..that check for a custom annotation that identifies the fallback pageable in its supportsParameter method".

Comment: Ok i get it. I overwrite the method supportsParameter in my customResolver and write the condition inside, whether to use this Resolver for the caller method. But it still sounds a bit strange having so many Resolver classes for each default pagination.. If i have nearly 10 different pagination mechanisms, i must have 10 different Resolver classes, just to set the default condition.

Comment: @Cimbom Alternatively you can have a single resolver with a map of IDs to `Pageable` instances. The additional annotation would just specify which ID to use to get a `PageAble`. This is adding an extra dependency but it is kind of unavoidable (at least I can't think of another way right now).